# Run puma workers in Production, but not in Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma, devops

I'm running the following puma config

```
threads_count = Integer(ENV["DB_POOL"] || ENV["MAX_THREADS"] || 15)
threads threads_count, threads_count
workers 3
preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV["PORT"]     || 3000
environment ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end

before_fork do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!
end
```

It's great for production, but I don't want to spin up 3 workers or use webrick in development. I tried wrapping the worker specific code in an environment check, but that breaks the puma DSL. Any ideas for running puma in non-clustered  mode in development?

Comment: _"that breaks the puma DSL"_ – could you be more specific? The file looks like Ruby syntax.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that when I wrapped it in a check puma through an error about `workers`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Rails` is not defined in puma config file, so `Rails.env` can't be used here, but `RACK_ENV` is ok.

```
workers(ENV["RACK_ENV"] == "production" ? 3 : 0)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware you could set workers as 0. Cool, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I figure out a working solution before seeing scorix's answer which I accepted, but I ended up with a slightly different solution. This allows you to set the worker count, so I can run 1 in staging and 3 in production for example.

```
threads_count = Integer(ENV["DB_POOL"] || ENV["MAX_THREADS"] || 15)
threads threads_count, threads_count
rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV["PORT"]     || 3000
environment ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"

if ENV["RACK_ENV"] == "production"
  workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 3 }
  preload_app!
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
  before_fork do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Configuration](https://github.com/puma/puma#configuration-file) part on the docs.

What I did was set up the production config on `config/puma/production.rb`, so on production you would run puma with `puma -C config/puma/production.rb` (or however you run it on prod) and on development, `rails server` won't use that configuration